# How to replace partial content with ruby regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string containing this

```
some_string = "[quote=\"user.name, post:1, topic:14\"] some other content here"
```

And i'm looking to replace the number of post and topic, something like this:

```
"[quote=\"user.name, post:#{a}, topic:#{b}\"] whatevercontent"
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind

```
>> some_string = "[quote=\"user.name, post:1, topic:14\"] some other content here"
=> "[quote=\"user.name, post:1, topic:14\"] some other content here"
>> some_string.sub(/(?<=post:)[^,"]+/, 'aaa').sub(/(?<=topic:)[^,"]+/, 'bbb')
=> "[quote=\"user.name, post:aaa, topic:bbb\"] some other content here"
```

Explanation:

```
/(?<=post:)[^,"]+/
```

Is a string of non-comma, non-double-quote characters preceded by `post:`. We replace that, using the `sub` method, to `aaa`.

Then we do the same for the characters preceded by `topic:`, replacing that piece with `bbb`.

I assume that the parts you want to replace are those between the colon and either a comma or a double quote; adjust those characters if necessary.

Another approach is to not worry about a regex and invoke `split` to break up what you have into key value pairs and put everything back together with the new values. But if your use case is restricted enough, the regex approach above can work.

**ADDENDUM**

The OP wants to make sure that the replacement happens only within the bracketed part of the string and not anywhere else. Here is how that can be done, **assuming no square brackets inside the quote part (and therefore no nesting)**:

```
>> s = 'post:no change, [quote="user.name, post:1, topic:14"] topic:no change,'
=> "post:no change, [quote=\"user.name, post:1, topic:14\"] topic:no change,"
>> quote_part = s.scan(/\[quote[^\]]+\]/)[0]
=> "[quote=\"user.name, post:1, topic:14\"]"
>> new_quote_part = quote_part.sub(/(?<=post:)[^,"]+/, 'aaa').sub(/(?<=topic:)[^,"]+/, 'bbb')
=> "[quote=\"user.name, post:aaa, topic:bbb\"]"
>> s.sub(quote_part, new_quote_part)
=> "post:no change, [quote=\"user.name, post:aaa, topic:bbb\"] topic:no change,"
```

The last line has replacements only within the bracketed quote part.

Comment: Awesome but how can i do it for post: and topic: inside [quote=" "] only as this will replace post: and topic: that is outside of the quote

Comment: I would do that outside of the regex. Extract the `[quote...'] portion and apply the regex to _that part only_. Once you try to get too tricky and expect too much context, regexes become unwieldly. Also there are may problems regexes can't solve. If your text has nested structure, for example, then regexes will not work in general.

Comment: And may i ask how would you extract it?

Comment: If you know for sure that inside of the square brackets you will never have a right square bracket then you can simply say `some_string.scan(/\[quote[^\]]+\]/)` and that will return the bracketed part. :)

Comment: Added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
some_string = "[quote=\"user.name, post:1, topic:14\"] some other content here"
new_post = "2"
new_topic = "15"
some_string = some_string.sub(/post:\d+/, "post:#{new_post}").sub(/topic:\d+/, "topic:#{new_topic}")

puts some_string
```